# create 6 childs with fork() systemcall

Tags: c, fork, exec

I'm trying to write a program to create 6 children with fork system call that each of them run /bin/ls command with diffrent types of exec() function and when all children finished their works the parent should print out it's pid.
still giving wrong output with this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("hello world (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
    for (int i =0 ; i<6;i++)
    {
        char *myargs_path = "/bin/ls";
        char *myargs_file[2] = {"ls",NULL};
        char *myargs_temp[2] = {"done",NULL};
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                printf("hello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
                execl(myargs_path,myargs_path,NULL); 
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                printf("hello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
                execlp(myargs_file[0],myargs_file[0],NULL);
            }
            if (i == 2)
            {
                printf("hello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
                execle(myargs_path,myargs_path,NULL,myargs_temp);
            }
            if (i == 3)
            {
                printf("hello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
                execv(myargs_path,myargs_path);
            }
            if (i == 4)
            {
                printf("hello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
                execvp(myargs_file[0],myargs_file[0]);
            }
            if (i == 5)
            {
                printf("hello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
                execvpe(myargs_file[0],myargs_file,myargs_temp);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
         
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        int wc = wait(NULL);
        printf("hello, I am parent of %d (wc:%d) (pid:%d)\n",wc, wc, (int) getpid());
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try getting pid values returned by fork() and use waitpid(), instead.

Comment: Or use threads instead of this old, slow junk API...

Comment: The `myargs_temp` array is not initialized with viable environment strings.  Members other than the last should point to strings of the form `variable=value`.  And it is conceivable, if unlikely, that your `ls` requires an environment variable that you're not providing.

Comment: Also, you do not check for or handle failures of your exec calls, or your `fork` or `wait` calls, either.  These functions will return `-1` if they fail, and you will definitely get different output than you expect if in such cases the program just continues on as if they had succeeded.  Exec calls in particular return at all only if they fail, and it is usual to terminate the (child) process in that event.

Comment: I get a lot of incompatible pointer type warnings.  You are passing strings when you should be passing arrays in some instances. Pay attention to the compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few incorrect arguments.  You want:

```
                switch(i) {
                case 0: execl(myargs_path, myargs_path, NULL);
                        break;
                case 1: execlp(myargs_file[0], myargs_file[0], NULL);
                        break;
                case 2: execle(myargs_path, myargs_path, NULL, myargs_temp);
                        break;
                case 3: execv(myargs_path, myargs_file);
                        break;
                case 4: execvp(myargs_file[0], myargs_file);
                        break;
                case 5: execvpe(myargs_file[0], myargs_file, myargs_temp);
                        break;
                }
```